# How to get the logic block address of each IO opreation

Tags: python, python-2.7, io

I am using python to develop a tool used to trace IO. Now, I need to know the logical block address of each IO operation.The shell command blktrace is helpful for this purpose, but the overhead it produces is very high. And it also produces something that is not necessary to my tool.
  Does there exits some method which can be used?
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: For instance, I want to use this tool to get the logical block address of each IO operation. And after that, a graph can be produced by using these data. Through this graph, I can detect the mode my business running in the server and make adjustments so that the IO operations are much more continuous.